# Why do the System.IOUtils functions and TStreamReader use fmShareCompat?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, share, file-access

When I first saw the `System.IOUtils` unit with functions like `TFile.ReadAllBytes` and `TFile.ReadAllText` and the `TStreamReader` and `TBinaryReader` classes in `System.Classes` I was quite excited to have easy ways to read binary and text files.

After using them for a while I noticed that the default share mode is implicitly `fmShareCompat`, since they all use `TFileStream.Create`, but do not explicitly specify a share mode.

Since `fmShareCompat` is treated as `fmShareExclusive` on Windows this leads to file locking problems when using them.

Is this an oversight by the Delphi developers? Or is there a reason to not use `fmShareDenyWrite` by default?

Also why is there no way to specify a share mode?

I am now tempted to write my own version of these classes in order to make them more sharing friendly.

Comment: IIRC this is a giant balls up perpetrated by Emba. Recent releases fix this.